# How many $N$ of the form $2^n$ are there such that no digit is a power of $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

> How many $N$ of the form $2^n,\text{ with } n \in \mathbb{N}$ are there such that *no* digit is a power of $2$?

For this one the answer given is the $2^{16}$, but how could we prove that that this is the only possible solution? and what about the general case of $x^n, \text{ with } x,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Since we cannot use the digits $1,2,4$ and $8$, such numbers are unlikely.  My guess is $65536$ is the only one, now to find a proof.  For general $x$, it is reasonable that there are only a finite number.  No matter what, we at least cannot use the digit $1$, and if I take the power high enough it seems conceivable that I have to have a $1$ somewhere.  (The density of numbers without $1$'s is zero) But this is just a heuristic.

Comment: A quick brute force checks says there are no solutions below $2^{100000}$ except $2^{16}=65536$.

Comment: @Ilmari:Yes, but the question is how to prove that conclusively.

Comment: The last n digits in a sequence of powers of 2 will form a repeating cycle eventually, so if a brute force of all possible last 5 digits of powers of 2 finds only 65536, then it will be known that all possible solutions end in 65536.

Comment: We could extend Angela Richardson's idea by checking the last 6 digits of the number and finding the cycle.  This could easily be done by computer.  I see the contest-math tag though.  No idea how you'd do this without a computer.

Comment: 2^12506= 64 mod(10^6)

Comment: @Angela: I counted 76 different 5-digit endings of powers of 2 that don't contain 1, 2, 4, or 8 (the cycle length is 2500).

Comment: I think there are some unsolved problems nearby. For example, I think it has not been proved that for all sufficiently large $n$ there's a zero in the decimal representation of $2^n$. According to http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/?p=311 it's conjectured that 86 is the highest power of 2 with no zero.

Comment: $2^n$ has about $n \log_{10}(2)$ decimal digits, and heuristically it seems reasonable that (except for the first and last few) each has approximately "probability" $6/10$ of being $0,3,5,6,7$ or $9$, so the probability that $2^n$ is a solution is approximately $(6/10)^{n \log_{10}(2)} \approx 0.857^n$.  The expected number of solutions for $n \ge 17$ is then
about $0.857^{17}/(1 - 0.857) = 0.514$.  So it would be not at all surprising if there are none.

Comment: It is just a small simplification - but by looking at what happens mod 10 you should realise that we only need to look at powers of 16.

Answer (score 6):

Define the *acceptable* digits to be 0, 3, 5, 6, 7, and 9; and define the *score* of a number $n$ to be the number of trailing acceptable digits in the decimal expansion of $n$ (with no leading zeroes). So for instance 65536 has a score of 5, and $2^{96} = 79228162514264337593543950336$ has a score of 7 (and this is the smallest power of $2$ with a score greater than 5).

I did a computer search for high-scoring powers of $2$ up to $2^{332192}$ (i.e. those with less than 100000 decimal digits). The highest-scoring was $2^{57072}$, with a score of only 25 (it ends with ...40535076966633036050333696).

So your conjecture is plausible, but it looks like one of those things that could be very difficult to prove.

Comment: Downvoted only because it's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Greg: You think I should have put all this in a comment? Don't be silly.