# Interesting patterns in digits of decimal expansion of powers of 2

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Analyzing powers of $2$ after finding this [interesting question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873371/is-216-65536-the-only-power-of-2-that-has-no-digit-which-is-a-power-of), I found some patterns that keep me intrigued, and that can be visualized in the following table:

[image]

**First Pattern:**

Let us denote as $S(2^k)$ the sum of digits of the decimal expansion of $2^k$. Then, as it can be seen in the table, **it seems that $S(2^n)=S(2^m)$, with $m\geq n$, only if $m-n=6$**. For instance, $S(2^3)=S(2^9)$, $S(2^{10})=S(2^{16})$, $\dots$

**Second Pattern:**

**The number of powers of 2 being digits of $2^k$ seems to follow some kind of palindromic symmetries.** For instance, $\{1,3,1\}$, $\{2,3,3,1,3,3,2\}$, $\dots$

**Third Pattern (related to first pattern?):**

It seems that $S(2^{2n})=3n+1$, and when it is not the case, the digits of the decimal expansion of $2^{2n}$ can be arranged in subsequences such that its sum is $3n+1$. For instance, $2^{2*9}=262144$, and $2+6+2+14+4=28=3*9+1$.

It seems that $S(2^{2n+1})$ has some kind of pattern too, but I have not been able to identify it completely; only that $S(2^{2n+1})=3k+2$ and $S(2^{2m+1})-S(2^{2n+1})=3x$, with $k,x\in \mathbb Z$

I am a bit lost trying to understand why this patterns arise, so any help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: As a cheap remark:  Note that $S(m)\equiv m\pmod 9$ and that the order of $2\pmod 9$ is $6$.  Thus $S(2^{m+6})\equiv S(2^m)\pmod 9$ at least.  If $S(2^{m+k})=S(2^m)$ then $k$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: The pair $[128175, 129675]$ exhibits $m-n=1500$ and the digitsum is $174\ 518$ in both cases.

Comment: @lulu thanks! Really insightful comment!

Comment: @Peter great counterexample to the first pattern. Is it the first one that you have found? A bit hard to calculate...

Comment: It is the smallest with EXACT difference $1500$ , but need not be the smallest with difference larger than $1500$

Comment: In fact, this beats my counterexample : $[65215, 66859, 1644]$ , digitsum in both case is $89\ 507$. In fact significantly more extreme. I guess that the palindrome pattern also eventually breaks away.

Comment: My current record for the difference occurs here : $[233725, 237637, 3912]$

Comment: PARI/GP can easily calculate the digitsums. The last pair has common sum $318\ 593$

Comment: @Peter I also guess that the palindrome pattern eventually breaks away; too amazing to be true! But I still wonder what does generate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By arranging the decimal expansion of a number in subsequences we can only increase the digit sum. Therefore, the third pattern cannot hold for $n \in \{16, 17, 18, 19, 33, 37, 47, 75, 76, 93, ...\}$ because the digit sum of $4^n$ is bigger than $3n + 1$.

$$4^{16} = 4294967296 \quad \to 58 > 49 = 3 \cdot 16 + 1$$

However, assuming the digits of $4^n$ are uniformly distributed the expected value of the digit sum is $9n \lg2 = 2.71n$ which is always smaller than $3n + 1$ so your pattern should hold for almost all numbers.

[image]

By arranging the decimal expansion of a number in subsequences we can only increase the digit sum by multiples of nine.

$$S(25139) = 20 \qquad \begin{array}{l} 2 + 5 + \mathbf{1}3 + 9 = 29 = S(25139) + 9 \cdot \mathbf{1} \\ 2 + \mathbf{5}1 + 3 + 9 = 65 = S(25139) + 9 \cdot \mathbf{5} \end{array}$$

Conveniently, the difference between the digit sum of $4^n$ and $3n + 1$ is always divisible by nine:

$$ S(4^n) \equiv \begin{cases} 1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{cases} \mod{9} \iff n \equiv \begin{cases} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{cases} \mod{3}$$
$$\implies 3n + 1 - S(4^n) \equiv 0 \mod{9}$$

So if the digit sum of $4^n$ is smaller than $3n+1$ we know the subsequence needs to start at the digit $$x(n) = \frac{3n + 1 - S(4^n)}9$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} n & 4^n & x(n) & 3n + 1 = \\ \hline 5 & 1024 & 1 & 10 + 2 + 4 \\ 29 & 288230376151711744 & 2 & 28 + 8 + \cdots \\ 35 & 1180591620717411303424 & 4 & \cdots + 3 + 42 + 4 \end{array}$$

---

In some cases like $$4^{21} = 4398046511104 \qquad x(21) = 2 = 1+1 \qquad 64 = \cdots + 5 + 11 + 10 + 4$$

and for $x(n) \geq 10$ we need multiple subsequences where $x(n)$ is the sum of their inital digits

$$4^{185} \approx 240490760476040522535882813 \dots$$
$$\begin{align} x(185) = 13 & = 4 + 9 & 556 & = 2 + 40 + 4 + 90 + \cdots \\ & = 3 \cdot 4  + 1 & & = 2 + 40 + 49 + 7 + 6 + 47 + \cdots + 13 + \cdots \end{align} $$

Because the number of partitions of $x(n)$ increases superpolynomially it should be possible to find an arangement for almost all numbers.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Nice analysis of the third pattern

Comment: That the digitsum is small enough does not mean that we can get EXACTLY $3n+1$ in the desired way. Actually, I would guess that this is possible very rarely.

Comment: @Peter feel free to find a counterexample